# R New column based on content of other columns by subject

Tags: r

I would like to create a new column based on the content of other columns, and separate the desired value in the new column by each subject.

In the following example, I want to be able to go from this:

```
Subject = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
var = c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3)
OBS = c(5,10,15,20,2,4,5,7)
df1 = data.frame(Subject,var,OBS)
```

to this

```
Subject = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
var = c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3)
OBS = c(5,10,15,20,2,4,5,7)
newOBS0 = c(5,5,5,5,2,2,2,2)
df2 = data.frame(Subject,var,OBS,newOBS0)
```

In other words, I want to create a new column which only contains the OBS for var = 0 for Subject = 1 and Subject = 2, respectively. I will then be able to expand this for e.g. variable = 1 and get this:

```
Subject = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
var = c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3)
OBS = c(5,10,15,20,2,4,5,7)
newOBS0 = c(5,5,5,5,2,2,2,2)
newOBS1 = c(10,10,10,10,4,4,4,4)
df3 = data.frame(Subject,var,OBS,newOBS0,newOBS1)
```

Second scenario: var column consists of character instead of numbers. Furthermore the sequence for the var has been changed for the two subjects.

```
Subject = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
var = c('b','a','d','c','a','b','c','d')
OBS = c(10,5,20,15,2,4,5,7)
df1 = data.frame(Subject,var,OBS)
df1$var <- paste(df1$var)
```

Hope anyone can help.

Sincerily,

ykl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `data.table`.  If you want to create `new` columns the first `two` `OBS` (assuming that the data is ordered by `var`).

```
library(data.table)
```

Create column names using `paste`

```
nm1 <- paste0("newOBS", 0:1)
```

Use `setDT` to convert the `data.frame` to `data.table`.  Assign `nm1` which has the `colnames` to the first two `OBS`, ie. `OBS[1]` and `OBS[2]` per each Subject `by=Subject`.

```
setDT(df1)[,(nm1):=list(OBS[1],OBS[2]) , by=Subject][]
#    Subject var OBS nm1 newOBS0 newOBS1
#1:       1   0   5   5       5      10
#2:       1   1  10   5       5      10
#3:       1   2  15   5       5      10
#4:       1   3  20   5       5      10
#5:       2   0   2   2       2       4
#6:       2   1   4   2       2       4
#7:       2   2   5   2       2       4
#8:       2   3   7   2       2       4
```

For all the `unique` values.  The logic is similar to the above.  Only difference is we are creating the columns for the whole values in `OBS` for each `Subject`.

```
 nm1 <- paste0('newOBS', unique(df1$var))
 setDT(df1)[, (nm1) := as.list(OBS), by=Subject][]
 #    Subject var OBS newOBS0 newOBS1 newOBS2 newOBS3
 #1:       1   0   5       5      10      15      20
 #2:       1   1  10       5      10      15      20
 #3:       1   2  15       5      10      15      20
 #4:       1   3  20       5      10      15      20
 #5:       2   0   2       2       4       5       7
 #6:       2   1   4       2       4       5       7
 #7:       2   2   5       2       4       5       7
 #8:       2   3   7       2       4       5       7
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>% 
     group_by(Subject) %>%
     mutate(newOBS1=OBS[1], newOBS2=OBS[2])
```

#### Update

Suppose the `var` column is not numeric and not ordered

```
 set.seed(295)
 df1$var <- sample(letters[1:5], 8, replace=TRUE)

 #create the data.table and use `setkey` that
 #will also order the columns `Subject`, `var`
 setkey(setDT(df1), Subject, var)
 #create the column names
 nm1 <- paste0('newOBS', c('ca', 'db'))
 #nm1 <- paste0('newOBS', c('aa', 'bb')) #for the updated post

 df1[, (nm1):= list(OBS[1], OBS[2]), by=Subject][]
 #      Subject var OBS newOBSca newOBSdb
 #1:       1   c  10       10        5
 #2:       1   d   5       10        5
 #3:       1   e  15       10        5
 #4:       1   e  20       10        5
 #5:       2   a   4        4        2
 #6:       2   b   2        4        2
 #7:       2   c   5        4        2
 #8:       2   c   7        4        2
```

Comment: Wow, seems very simple. Thanks for your answer. Mind explaining what happens in the second and third lines of the code?

Comment: the plyr package might also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @akrun. Last request, let's say the values in var are characters instead of nunmeric values. Any idea of what to do then?

Comment: @ykl Could you update the post with var as characters along with expected result.  I didn't use the `var` column here in the code.  You can use `sort` or `order` to order that column by Subject (if not ordered) and then apply the code.

Comment: The issue arises after I sort by subject. The variables (now characters instead of numerics) are not sorted which makes it difficult to assign by "first two OBS", again since these are unorganized and not the first two, merely in random sequence. Please see updated post.

Comment: @ykl Thanks, I will check. DId you updated the post?  Couldn't find any updates.  You have to sort by `subject` and `var`

Comment: @ykl It should work using the `Updated` code.  For example change the `nm1 <- paste0('newOBS', c('aa', 'bb'))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can sort your data such that the observations are continuous for each subject (no missing data), you can do

```
df1<-df1[order(df1$Subject, df1$var),]  #ensure sort order
transform(df1,
   newOBS0=ave(OBS, Subject, FUN=function(x) x[1]),
   newOBS1=ave(OBS, Subject, FUN=function(x) x[2]))

#   Subject var OBS newOBS0 newOBS1
# 1       1   0   5       5      10
# 2       1   1  10       5      10
# 3       1   2  15       5      10
# 4       1   3  20       5      10
# 5       2   0   2       2       4
# 6       2   1   4       2       4
# 7       2   2   5       2       4
# 8       2   3   7       2       4
```

If you want to do this for all OBS values, you might think of it in terms of a reshape. And the you can merge the wide data back to the original. For example

```
wide<-reshape(df1, direction="wide", timevar="var",idvar="Subject")
merge(df1, wide)

#   Subject var OBS OBS.0 OBS.1 OBS.2 OBS.3
# 1       1   0   5     5    10    15    20
# 2       1   1  10     5    10    15    20
# 3       1   2  15     5    10    15    20
# 4       1   3  20     5    10    15    20
# 5       2   0   2     2     4     5     7
# 6       2   1   4     2     4     5     7
# 7       2   2   5     2     4     5     7
# 8       2   3   7     2     4     5     7
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let's say we now dont have numeric values in the columns, but instead character values - anyway of doing the same?

Comment: I don't see anything here that wouldn't work with character values. Are you having a problem?